# Index structure for secondary keyword search

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance, query-performance

I have a table(Articles) with the following structure:

```
id int(10) unsigned not_null auto_increment
title varchar(32)
system_id int(10) unsigned default 0
last_update int(10) unsigned default 0
```

what is the recommended index structure for the table that will provide best performance for this query :

```
"SELECT * FROM Articles where system_id = {ID} order by last_update desc"
```

Comment: An index on `system_id` and `last_update` should improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) , start with the `=` column (`system_id`), then have the "range" column (`last_update`):

```
INDEX(system_id, last_update)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add both these indexes and check the EXPLAIN plan to see which of them are used. MySQL sometimes chooses the ordering index rather than the filtering one, and therefore the second one might be better in some cases.

```
ALTER TABLE `Articles` ADD INDEX `articles_index_1` (system_id, last_update);
ALTER TABLE `Articles` ADD INDEX `articles_index_1` (last_update);
```